# Null value in a concurrent hashmap cache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

I'm trying to implement a concurrent cache in java for learning propose.

This code is responsable for garantee thread-safy operations. So, whenever a thread try to fetch a value, if this value is not already cached, the algorithm should calculate it from the last cached one.

My problem is that i'm getting null values that are supposed to be already cached. I'm using semaphore (though i've tried with ReentrantLock too, so i think it's not the problem) to assure the thread-safety access to an HashMap.

Note that i would like to restrict the locked area to the smallest possible. So i would not like to synchronize the entire method or utilize an already thread safe ConcurrentMap.

Here is a complete simple code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ConcurrentCache {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> cache;
    private int lastCachedNumber;

    public ConcurrentCache() {
        cache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        cache.put(0, 0);
        lastCachedNumber = 0;
    }

    public Integer fetchAndCache(int n) {

        //if it's already cached, supposedly i can access it in an unlocked way
        if (n <= lastCachedNumber)  
            return cache.get(n);

        lock();

        Integer number;
        if (n < lastCachedNumber) { // check it again. it may be updated by another thread
            number = cache.get(n);
        } else {
            //fetch a previous calculated number.
            number = cache.get(lastCachedNumber);   

            if (number == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                        "this should be cached. n=%d, lastCachedNumber=%d", n,
                        lastCachedNumber));

            for (int i = lastCachedNumber + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                number = number + 1;
                cache.put(i, number);
                lastCachedNumber = i;
            }
        }

        unlock();

        return number;
    }

    private void lock() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void unlock() {
        semaphore.release();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentCache cachedObject = new ConcurrentCache();
        for (int nThreads = 0; nThreads < 5; nThreads++) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int cacheValue = 0; cacheValue < 1000; cacheValue++) {

                        if (cachedObject.fetchAndCache(cacheValue) == null) {

                            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                                    "the number %d should be cached",
                                    cacheValue));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }
    } 
}
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: I know you are trying to implement this in a multi-threaded manner, but have you first confirmed that your version of this algorithm works using a single thread?

Comment: Yes @NoseKnowsAll, it works in a single thread manner.

Comment: When i try to lock in the very beginning  it seems to work, though i think i've got an exception once. Anyway, i don't know what i'm missing since `if (n <= lastCachedNumber)  return cache.get(n);`  should respect the happens-before relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few pointers/ideas:
1) pre-size your `Map` when you create it to accommodate all/many of your future cached values, `Map` resizing is very thread unsafe and time consuming
2) you can simplify your whole algorithm to

```
YourClass.get(int i) {
    if (!entryExists(i)) {
        lockEntry(i);
        entry = createEntry(i);
        putEntryInCache(i, entry);
        unlockEntry(i);
    }
    return entry;
}
```

**Edit**
Another point:
3) your approach to caching is very bad - imagine what will happen if the 1st request is to get something @ position 1,000,000?
Pre-populate in separate thread is going to be a lot better...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but 
1) Pre-size should really be a good practice if you know the amount expected. But i would like to cache indefinitely until reach a condition.  
2) your pseudo code it's not exactly the one as i said before. If the entry is not yet cached, it needs to calculate it based in  the last one cached. I wrote a dummy example above, but in fact i'm doing complex calculations.

Comment: Calculate based on last cached to me sounds like `getLastCachedValue()` and make some calculations. That is the reason why I suggested simplification. If you meant previous sequence than it is better to use an array for data storage

Comment: Yes, you could rewrite the original code `number = cache.get(lastCachedNumber);` to `getLastCachedValue()` or `cache.put(i, number);  lastCachedNumber = i;`  to  `putEntryInCache(i, entry);` but it's not the point. The concerning is why this actual implementation using hashmap is not thread-safe.

Comment: The Javadoc only states: **"Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally"**.

It's exactly what i'm trying to do.

Comment: When the `Map` is resized due to added elements the whole `Map` is copied into new bigger `Map` - this process is long and may miss (not copy) any new entries added to the `Map` by other threads after the resize has started.

Comment: Definitely it's the case. A simple test can be done. Caching 100 elements without pre-size it (pre-sizing it to a value that not respect the 0.75 rate) the error occurs. On the other hand, the same algorithm works in a 150 pre-sized table. Thanks